# How to change the size of material table in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, rxjs, material-table

Anyone can tell me how to change the size of a table created with material table?
I'm using React and this code doesn't work. I've tried also with 'react-virtualized-auto-sizer' and it doesn't work.

```
options={{
        cellStyle: {
          width: 100,
          maxWidth: 100,
        },
        headerStyle: {
          width: 100,
          maxWidth: 100,
        },
      }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `maxWidth` use `minWidth`. Some times `maxWidth` works over 100.

```
    options={{
        cellStyle: {
          width: 100,
          minWidth: 100,
        },
        headerStyle: {
          width: 100,
          minWidth: 100,
        },
      }}
```